# find max value for index in dataframe and latest value

Tags: python, dataframe, aggregate

In the following dataframa I would like to substract the max value of `u` from each user to the value of `u` with the corresponding row of the max value of `t`. So it should be like 21 (u-max) - 18 (u-value of t-max).
The dataframe is grouped by `['user','t']`

```
user  t      u
1     0.0    -1.14
      2.30   2.8
      2.37   9.20
      2.40   21
      2.45   18
2     ...    ...
```

If `t` wasn't part of the index, I would have used something like `df.groupby().agg({'u':'max'})` and `df.groupby().agg({'t':'max'})` ,but since it isn't, I don't know how I could use `agg()`on `t`

*(edit)*
I found out that I can use `df.reset_index(level=['t'], inplace=True)` to change t into a column, but now I realise that if I would use
`df.groupby(['user']).agg({"t":'max'})` , that the corresponding `u` values would be missing

The goal is to create a new dataframe that contains the values like this:

```
user    (U_max - U_tmax) 
1        3
2        ...
```

Comment: Are you able to add a visual representation of your desired output?

Comment: I have added some extra info. I hope that it is a little bit more understandable what the ouput should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by re-creating a dataframe similar to yours, with the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols =  ['user', 't', 'u']
df  = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
size = 10

df['user'] = np.random.randint(1,3, size=size)
df['t'] = np.random.uniform(0.0,3.0, size=size)

df = df.groupby(['user','t']).sum()
df['u'] = np.random.randint(-30,30, size=len(df))

print(df)
```

The output is something like:

```
                u
user t           
1    0.545562  19
     0.627296  23
     0.945533 -13
     1.697278 -18
     1.904453 -10
     2.008375   5
     2.296342  -2
2    0.282291  14
     1.461548  -6
     2.594966 -19
```

The first thing we'll need to do in order to work on this df is to reset the index, so:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Now we have all our columns back and we can use them to apply our final `groupby()` function.

We can start by grouping by `user`, which is what we need, specifying `u` and `t` as columns, so that we can access them in a lambda function.

In this lambda function, we will subtract from the `max` value of `u` and the corresponding `u` value for the `max` value of `t`.

So, the max value of `u` must be something like:

```
x['u'].max()
```

And the `u` value of `max` of `t` should look like:

```
x['u'][x['t'].idxmax()])
```

So as you can see we've found the index for the max value of `t`, and used it to slice `x['u']`.

Here is the **final code**:

```
df = df.reset_index()

df = df.groupby(['user'])['u', 't'].apply(lambda x: (x['u'].max() - x['u'][x['t'].idxmax()]) )

print(df)
```

**Final output:**

```
user
1    25
2    33
```

**Gross Error Check:**

- `max` of `u` for `user 1` is **23**
- `max` of `t` for `user 1` is `2.296342`, and the corresponding `u` is **-2**

`23 - (-2)` = **25**

- `max` of `u` for `user 2` is **14**
- `max` of `t` for `user 2` is `2.594966`, and the corresponding `u` is **-19**

`14 - (-19)` = **33**

**Bonus tip:** If you'd like to rename the returned column from `groupby`, use `reset_index()` along with `set_index()` after the groupby operation:

```
df = df.reset_index(name='(U_max - U_tmax)').set_index('user')
```

It will yield:

```
      (U_max - U_tmax)
user                  
1                   25
2                   33
```